# Adding an key=> value pair comparing the **key of one array** with the **value of another array**

Tags: php, associative-array, array-difference

I have an associative array (name = $holidays) like below. Each key might or might not point to a value. If a key points to a value that value is an array as shown below. (key [4] points to an Array which has the key=> value pair [override] => 1 )

```
Array
(
    [1] =>                       
    [2] =>                       
    [3] =>                       
    [4] => Array                 
                        (
                           [override] => 1
                        )

    [5] =>                       
    [6] =>                
    [7] =>
)
```

I have another 2D associative array (name = $days)  like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [a] => 1
            [b] => 20120903
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Mon
            [e] => 3
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 1
            [j] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [a] => 2
            [b] => 20120904
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Tue
            [e] => 4
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [a] => 3
            [b] => 20120905
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Wed
            [e] => 5
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [a] => 4
            [b] => 20120906
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Thu
            [e] => 6
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [a] => 5
            [b] => 20120907
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Fri
            [e] => 7
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [a] => 6
            [b] => 20120908
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Sat
            [e] => 8
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [a] => 7
            [b] => 20120909
            [c] => 1
            [d] => Sun
            [e] => 9
            [f] => September
            [g] => Sep
            [h] => 9
            [i] => 
            [j] => 
        )

)
```

I basically need to do a compare between the 2 arrays like this: 
Get the first **key** of the $holidays array (lets name it as $val1)
then go to the $days array, access the first sub-array, get the **value** of the key [a] of that sub-array (lets name it as $val2), then check

> whether ($val1 and $val2) are same 
>              and
>   whether the key of the array $holiday holds a value (as I've mentioned above the keys of the $holiday array might not point to any values),

if both of those conditions are true
add a new key=>value pair to the relevant sub-array of $days array.
then move on to next elements of arrays and so on.

So, given the 2 arrays above, I want below array to return.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1346610600
                [b] => 20120903
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Mon
                [e] => 3
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 1
                [j] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1346697000
                [b] => 20120904
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Tue
                [e] => 4
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] => 
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1346783400
                [b] => 20120905
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Wed
                [e] => 5
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] => 
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1346869800
                [b] => 20120906
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Thu
                [e] => 6
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] =>
                [k] => 1 <<---------------- This is the new key value pair

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1346956200
                [b] => 20120907
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Fri
                [e] => 7
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] => 
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1347042600
                [b] => 20120908
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Sat
                [e] => 8
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] => 
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [a] => 1347129000
                [b] => 20120909
                [c] => 1
                [d] => Sun
                [e] => 9
                [f] => September
                [g] => Sep
                [h] => 9
                [i] => 
                [j] => 
            )

    )
```

Hope it is clear. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is pretty unclear at least for me, could you try to edit and explain a little further?

Comment: Your description is quite close to pseudocode. Did you try to write actual code that follows it?

Comment: i will never write solution for you anymore ....

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($holidays as $key => $value) {
    if(!is_array($value))
        continue;

    foreach($days as $dKey => $dValue) {
        if($key != $dValue['a'])
            continue;
        if(isset($dValue['k']) && $dValue['k'] == $value['override'])
            continue;

        end($dValue);
        $lastKey = key($dValue);

        $dValue[$lastKey++] = $value['override'];
        break;
    }
}

print_r($days);
```

Comment: this might work but i find few problems.... if $value is not array then you dont want to go to second loop .. it will save some processing time..... another one what if $dValue has k key already... that means we will overrite the value.. and may be the value is 1 always

Comment: I've changed my code.. I knew that this verifications should be made but I give you just the idea in how to start coding what you need.. now should be ok i think

Comment: again if isset($dValue['k']) is true then you want the new value on $dValue['l'], dont you? if last key of the day array is c probably you want to insert another data on d.... one more thing why always value is 1 what happens if [override] has value '5'

Comment: 1. You didn't specified that [override] can take different values. 2. Which is the link between a b c d e f g h i j k? what all of these represents. Are they dependant one of each other?

Comment: i am just guessing i am not the one who asked this question .... i have written another solution check that one... hehe

Comment: :)) I really though you are the person who asked the question and I've really wondered.. why is he asking me these thinks? I see that he knows very well how to code his example so.. wtf :)) You've got me on this :) He didn't gave us all the details we need so.. that's the results

Comment: did you realise that its not worth checking value for $dValue['k']... my whole point is it has nothing to do k key... all you need to do is put new value at the end of the array so isset($dValue['k'] is pointless... again ++ in character not convinced .. never tried though

Comment: So sorry it took me so long to get back to the question. I also had few problems when using 2 for-each loops and tried to find out whether i can use already implemented array functions. I thought of messing with the arrays because i assumed that I won't be able to do what i want in the template itself. But then again I was able to do most of of it in the template.  Thank you very much for your effort and sorry if i wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    foreach($holidays AS $hkey=>$hval){
        if(empty($hval))
            continue;
        foreach ($days as $day) {
            if($day['a'] != $hkey)
                continue;
            if(!is_array($hval))
                continue;

            end($day);
            $lastKey = key($day);
            $newLastKey = chr(ord($lastKey)+1);
            $day[$newLastKey] = $hval['override'];
            break;
        }

    }
```

this code is not tested .... try if you have problem then let me know i will try

Comment: do you know that you can replace `$newLastKey = chr(ord($lastKey)+1);` with `$lastKey++` ? :)

Comment: did you realise $lastKey is not integer but a character??? never tried ++ for character